# How to select a 'sensitivity' value for my circular hough transform?

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, mathematical-optimization

I'm using circular hough transform to detect circles in a image. There are four basic parameters which are necessary for the circular hough function:

1. Image name
2. Radius range
3. Object polarity (For my case, it is dark)
4. Sensitivity value (Default - 0.5)

> [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(img1,[r1
>   r2],'ObjectPolarity','dark', ... 'Sensitivity',sens);

Sensitivity value varies between 0 and 1.Here, I'm varying the sensitivity value between 0.9 and 0.95(Number of circles detected increases with sensitivity value. Maximum=1). For different images, optimum results are yielded at different sensitivity values.

[image: Input image - 1.jpg]

Let's say for '1.jpg' with radius range [3,8], the function provided different results(No. of circles) for different sensitivity values:

- 0.90 -> 553
- 0.91 -> 958
- 0.92 -> 1412
- 0.93 -> 1799
- 0.94 -> 2164
- 0.95 -> 2453
- 0.96 -> 2806
- 0.97 -> 3170
- 1.00 -> 6393

But for this image, the more accurate value is found between 0.94 and 0.95 (can be 0.941,0.942...,0.949 etc.,). Count is found to be 2200-2400. It has a lot of false positives if I have used values between [0.96,1].

I'm in need of a function, which has to tell me when to stop changing sensitivity based on a sudden increase in count.(i.e) a stable state is attained.

For the above case, it attains a stable state between [0.94-0.96].(i.e) The output value changes gradually between these points(2100,2400,2800).

[image: Variation of count with sensitivity]

Is there any mathematical technique to stop the count, based on rate of change of values? 
Or is there any other better solution to overcome my problem?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The sensitivity values to be used in the algorithm are usually found by trial and error basis.  The same range of sensitivity values will not work between different images.  Unfortunately this is an experimentation step and there's no way that I know of that will find the most optimum range of sensitivity values given an image.

Comment: I'm not asking for the exact sensitivity value. In the above case, there is a 'slightly' stable state occurring between [0.94,0.96]. Before and after that , value rises drastically. What I'm looking for, is a mathematical way to find the range (like gradient method,exponential graph etc.,). Or else I've to do trial and error for each frame of the video. My priority is to find the stable state's range.

Comment: There isn't a mathematical range.  You have to do it by trial and error.  I don't think there is a mathematically known range - it all depends on the content of the video and even then, I'm not familiar with such a formulation.  This is why you need to look into **tracking**.  Detect an initial set of circles, then **track** these circles over the next frames until the next shot is detected.  Using `imfindcircles` on a frame-by-frame basis is computationally intensive.  Even so, there are better solutions out there to track people over video.

Comment: If the camera is fixed, we can use background  subtraction and can relate frame-by-frame. My camera is mounted on a drone, which will be always moving. It is difficult to relate the previous frame with the current frame.

Comment: Sure you can. Use tracking algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It really helped me to take a different approach.